# JSP/Servlet expression language private variable access

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I am learning JSP and Servlet and I found something odd - If I use the following code:

```
request.setAttribute("m", m);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

where `request` is an `HttpServletRequest` object and `m` is an object of the `Model` class, I can access and display the values of the private variables of `m` in my JSP page (welcome.jsp).

Relevant JSP code for welcome.jsp:

```
Hello, <strong>${m.name}</strong>! Your data has been validated and is displayed below:<br/>
<br/>
Number: <strong> ${m.number} </strong>
<br/>
<br/>
Birth Month: <strong> ${m.month} </strong>
```

Relevant Java code for the Model class:

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String[] hobby;
    private int month;
    // remaining code...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
${m.name}
```

does basically the same as the following in "raw" scriptlet code

```
<%
  Model m = (Model) pageContext.findAttribute("m");
  if (m != null) {
  String name = m.getName();
   if (name != null) {
    out.print(name);
   }
 }
%>
```

`${m.name}` calls `getName()` which is `public` in class `Model`.
Do not get *confused* it is not accessing `private` variable `name` directly.

### Referred link

- [EL info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean to say that accessing a private variable in EL is not done directly, rather the getter is called internally at runtime?

Comment: @gamerteen_11 : Yes. To learn more please refer above mentioned link.